# how do you see your read queries in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I look at my firestore usage, I have 10s of thousands of "reads" and that seems excessive to me considering the usage of the site.  I've done a lot of tuning (making sure to pull back as few documents as possible) but it didn't seem to help.  I can't seem to find on the dashboard anywhere under usage where I can see what queries are hammering the database so I can try and fix it.  Is there  anywhere where it shows what queries are being run?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to see what queries are being performed.

Bear in mind that viewing your database in the Firebase console will incur document reads in order to populate the screen.  Leaving the console open will continue to incur reads as the database changes, since those changes might be reflected in real time.

Comment: While I'm not thrilled with this answer, if it is the way it is, then I guess it is... Do you know how to provide feedback?  A log on what's triggering the query as well as how many "reads" it's consuming would be very helpful.

Comment: You can always file a feature request here: https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support?page=bug_or_feature

Comment: Did that and they responded with a "We'll put it on our list of things to do".  Hopefully they do a better job of that then AWS.

Comment: The priorities of the team shifts over time. But it helps to know how many people would like the feature.